# How can i disable mobile scrolling? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website that displays 'The Game of Life', showing a canvas with the cells. On mobile, you can touch the canvas and it draws some cells, but it also scrolls the screen a little bit, even if the content of the web doesn't occupy more than 80% of the screen.
I've tried using

```
body {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it didn't work [Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSY9V.jpg)

Comment: did you set the viewport property?

Comment: what property? my css body properties are these:
body {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: @jbarcos https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDITED!!
I finally solved it. In my CSS i put this:

```
html, body {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Maybe it doesn't work for everyone, but solved my problem.
Buttons still work properly :)

EDIT:
I needed to activate the touch action in the rest of the website, so i replaced the code above, applying it only to the canvas

```
canvas {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

This allowed to zoom or scroll in the rest of the web, while not in the actual game

Comment: The scroll will still exist, this only will disable the touch action.

Comment: I just wanted to disable the scrolling on mobile devices, because it made the game so annoying. As my problem was that, this fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
   overscroll-behavior: none; 
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No, it just shakes. It only happens on mobile

Comment: Tried it with the editable and got it to stop shaking with overscroll-behavior: none;